# FileHelpers: Searching into results

Tags: c#, windows, parsing, filehelpers

I use the powerful [FileHelpers Library](http://www.filehelpers.net). But is there a built-in way to search over the generated objets.

```
var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Text>();
var res = engine.ReadFile("myfile.csv");
string result = res["key"].value;
```

My csv is like : key;value
I mean, is it possible not to access objects with the array [0], [1], [12]...
maybe like in the code example.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your resulting array to a dictionary via LINQ with:

```
var dictionary = validRecords.ToDictionary(r => r.Key, r => r.Value);
```

The following complete program demonstrates the approach.

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class ImportRecord
{
    public string Key;
    public string Value;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var engine = new FileHelperEngine<ImportRecord>();

        string fileAsString = @"Key1,Value1" + Environment.NewLine +
                              @"Key2,Value2" + Environment.NewLine;

        ImportRecord[] validRecords = engine.ReadString(fileAsString);

        var dictionary = validRecords.ToDictionary(r => r.Key, r => r.Value);

        Assert.AreEqual(dictionary["Key1"], "Value1");
        Assert.AreEqual(dictionary["Key2"], "Value2");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I thought, it's great that you confirm my ideas. Thanks !